# Getting minimum of rolling window in pandas

Tags: pandas, scipy

I am trying to obtain the minimum value of three consecutive cells in pandas. The calculation should take into account the one cell above and one below.

I have tried scipy's argelextrema but I have a feeling it does not perform a rolling window.

Thanks

This is a wild approach but it did not perform as expected.

```
def pivot_swing_low(df):
    data = df.copy()
    data['d1'] = data.Close.shift(-1)
    data['d3'] = data.Close.shift(0)
    data['d4'] = data.Close.shift(1)
    data['minPL'] = data[['d1', 'd3', 'd4']].min(axis=1)
    data['PL'] = np.where(data['minPL'] == data['d3'], data['d3'], "NaN")
    
    data['recentPL'] = data.PL.shift(2).astype(float).fillna(method='ffill')

    data = data.drop(columns=['d1', 'd3', 'd4'])
    return data
```

It will always capture the row number 33, but to me row 31 is relevant as well.

38.78   1671068699999   2022-12-15 01:44:59.999     NaN     NaN     -0.37   0.00    0.37    0.023571    0.054286    0.023125    0.057698    0.400805    28.612474   NaN     NaN     38.78   38.78   39.15
30  38.79   1671068999999   2022-12-15 01:49:59.999     NaN     NaN     0.01    0.01    0.00    0.022857    0.054286    0.022188    0.053576    0.414137    29.285496   NaN     NaN     38.48   NaN     39.15
31  38.48   1671069299999   2022-12-15 01:54:59.999     NaN     NaN     -0.31   0.00    0.31    0.021429    0.076429    0.020603    0.071892    0.286583    22.274722   22.274722   NaN     38.48   38.48   38.78
32  38.67   1671069599999   2022-12-15 01:59:59.999     NaN     NaN     0.19    0.19    0.00    0.035000    0.074286    0.032703    0.066757    0.489878    32.880419   NaN     NaN     38.37   NaN     38.78
33  38.37   1671069899999   2022-12-15 02:04:59.999     38.37000000     NaN     -0.30   0.00    0.30    0.035000    0.093571    0.030367    0.083417    0.364036    26.688174   NaN     NaN     38.37   38.37   38.48
34  38.58   1671070199999   2022-12-15 02:09:59.999     NaN     NaN     0.21    0.21    0.00    0.050000    0.090000    0.043198    0.077459    0.557687    35.802263   NaN     NaN     38.37   NaN     38.48
35  38.70   1671070499999   2022-12-15 02:14:59.999     NaN     NaN     0.12    0.12    0.00    0.058571    0.090000    0.048684    0.071926    0.676857    40.364625   NaN     40.364625   38.58   NaN     38.37

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Calculate the minimum of the current cell, the cell above, and the cell below
min_three_cells = df['value'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).min()

# View the results
print(min_three_cells)
```

This might help.